# iPhone: Programmatically find Internet Connectivity

Tags: iphone

What is the best way to find out internet connectivity on the device, programmatically? I found "Reachability" files, but i felt why should i use such huge files for finding just an internet connectivity status on the device? Is there anything else (or) I should go with only "Reachability" files as a standard?

Please share your thoughts.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check for an active Internet Connection on iPhone SDK?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083701/how-to-check-for-an-active-internet-connection-on-iphone-sdk)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reachability is the way to go. Don't worry about the file size, when compiled it won't bloat your binary too much. It is also maintained by apple, so you don't have to worry about it being harmful.